# Has J been used by itself as a spectral type?

Tags: spectral-type, carbon-star

While answering the question "[Why have brown dwarf classes been dubbed L, T and Y?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34738/24157)" I noticed that in the paper Kirkpatrick et al. (1999) "[Dwarfs Cooler than 'M': The Definition of Spectral Type 'L' Using Discoveries from the 2 Micron All-Sky Survey (2MASS)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ApJ...519..802K/abstract)", the letter "J" was ruled out as being in use as a standard carbon star type.

So far I have not seen a source that uses "J" as a carbon star type by itself, I've only seen it in combination with "C", e.g. "[C3,3J](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-5?-ref=VIZ5e39dd2e8016&-out.add=.&-source=V/137D/XHIP&recno=18648)" or "[C-J4 C2 5](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-5?-ref=VIZ5e39dd2e8016&-out.add=.&-source=V/137D/XHIP&recno=54631)" (both from XHIP). This contrasts with the other carbon star types "R" and "N" which have definitely been used as separate identifiers.

Has "J" ever been used as a stand-alone spectral type, e.g. "J3"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the J-type was introduced by [Bouigue (1954)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1954AnAp...17..104B), and have subsequently often called "J-type stars" or "J-stars", e.g. [Abia & Isern (2000)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2000MmSAI..71..631A). This likely led to the J-type designation being put as "in use", though the spectral types themselves appear to always have been used in combination with "C".